# SyntaxError in Jupypter notebook for msticpy QueryProvider

Tags: azure, jupyter-notebook, azure-data-explorer

I'm making use of **QueryProvider** in **msticpy.data.data_provider** to run a Kusto query statement in Jupyter notebook.

The purpose of the query is to extract a specific part of a string that is typically `session (other text)`, where I want to extract the `(other text)` - hence the extract function in Line 5.

As the content of the (other text) varies, I used the `\w+` in the regex.

I can't execute the query successfully as it keeps complaining of syntax error. I have tried to escape the characters but it seems to have no effect because the same error appear. Would anyone have an idea what is the issue? Or point me to any resources?

[Screenshot of current code and error returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8sx3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to escape the backslash (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/string#string-literals)

regardless, you'd be better off using the `parse` operator

```
print s = "session abc"
| extend session = extract(@"session (\w+)", 1, s)

print s = "session abc"
| parse s with "session " session
```

Comment: I had been using backslash to escape the backslash, no wonder it didn't work.. The first example has worked perfectly for me. Would check out the parse operator as well. Thanks much for your guidance!